# blocking url using firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

How can I control access to webpages in FireFox. I am going to develop a new addon.

Does FireFox extension programming allows this or should I develop a desktop application to control access.

edit: It is not going to be used daily. Will be just an example for research.

I want to develop an application/extension that will start to work if a user wants to open a webpage. Controls webpage using a webservice, developed before, then open requested webpage or deny and say this webpage cannot be accessed.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? How do you want to control web page access, and on what level? In Firefox only, or for all browsers in the system?

Comment: it's not going to be used daily. will be just an example for a research.

so i want to develop an application/extension that will start to work if a user wants to open a webpage. controls webpage using a webservice, developed before, then open requested webpage or deny and say this webpage cannot be accessed.

sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox addons can always be disable, user could use another browser. Better to use a desktop app. IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, and what the environment looks like, you could for example:

1. Use a custom filter with [Adblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865) to filter out certain URLs
2. Use a filtering HTTP proxy such as [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/)
3. Use a firewall to block certain remote servers